# Strange memory usage

Tags: java, performance, memory, ram

In the process of creating a voxel game, I'm doing some performance tests, for the basic chunk system.

A chunk is made of 16 tiles on the y axis. A tile is a Hashmap of material ids.
The key is a byte, and the material id is a short.

According to my calculations a chunk should be 12KB + a little bit (Let's just say 16KB). 16*16*16*3. 3 is for a byte and a short(3 bytes).

What I basically don't understand is that my application uses much more memory than expected. Actually around 256KB for each chunk. It uses around 2GB running 8192 chunks. Notice that this is chunk storage performance test, and therefore not a whole game.

Another strange thing is that the memory usage varies from 1.9GB to 2.2GB each time I run it. Theres no randomizer in the code, so it should always be the same amount of variables, arrays, elements etc.

Heres my code:

```
public class ChunkTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List <Chunk> chunks = new ArrayList <Chunk>();


        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for(int i = 0; i<8192; i++) {
            chunks.add(new Chunk());
        }

        long time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println(time2-time);

        System.out.println("Done");

        //System.out.println(chunk.getBlock((byte)0, (byte)0, (byte)0));

        while(1==1) {
            //Just to keep it running to view memory usage
        }


    }

}
```

And the other class

```
public class Chunk {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;

    boolean solidUp;
    boolean solidDown;
    boolean solidNorth;
    boolean solidSouth;
    boolean solidWest;
    boolean solidEast;

    private HashMap<Byte, HashMap<Byte, Short>> tiles = new HashMap<Byte, HashMap<Byte, Short>>();

    public Chunk() {
        HashMap<Byte, Short> tile;

        //Create 16 tiles
        for(byte i = 0; i<16;i++) {
            //System.out.println(i);
            tile = new HashMap<Byte, Short>();

            //Create 16 by 16 blocks (1 is the default id)
            for(short e = 0; e<256;e++) {
                //System.out.println(e);
                tile.put((byte) e, (short) 1);
            }

            tiles.put(i, tile);

        }
    }


    public short getBlock(byte x, byte y, byte z) {
        HashMap<Byte, Short> tile = tiles.get(y);

        short block = tile.get((byte)(x+(z*16)));

        return block;
    }

}
```

I'm using windows task manager to monitor the memory usage.
Is that a very inaccurate tool to monitor, and does it kind of guess, which would explain why it varies from instance to instance.

And what is making each chunk 20 times heavier than it should?

A little bonus question, if you know: If I know the index of what I'm trying to find, is hashMap or ArrayList faster?

Comment: I wouldn't rely on the Task Manager. AFAIK, the JDK ships with a profiler.

Comment: Ah okay. It seems like windows task manager is very inaccurate. But it still varies from 1.30GB to 1.35GB.

You meant the Java mission control right?

Comment: Java starts itself up with a certain amount of memory already allocated to the heap and the system sees that as non-free memory. It also runs garbage collection from time to time and decides when to return some memory to the system and when to allocate more.

Comment: @KaareZ I've never used it, so I'm not sure. I've seen people recommend it here though. I'm sure googling "JDK profiler" could lead you in the right direction.

Comment: There is no concept of an index in a `HashMap`; there are just keys and values. Lookup by key is fast (O(1)). If you only know the value, then for retrieving it from a `List`, you need to iterate through it -- there's no shortcut.

Comment: Those nested hashmaps don't look too good. Just use a flat `short[]` for minimum overhead.

Comment: What performance penalties you got faced with? This code looks somewhat strange to me and is maybe the result of premature optimization.

Comment: If you use a memory analyzer tool, like [MAT](https://eclipse.org/mat/), you can easily find out the retained size of your objects and where most of the waste is.

Comment: The windows task manager shows the memory allocated by the java process, but not how much of the heap is used. If you run your program with -Xms4g -Xmx4g you'll see that the task manager will show you a 4gb usage although the program might be a an empty main method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A chunk is made of 16 tiles on the y axis. A tile is a Hashmap of material ids. The key is a byte, and the material id is a short.
>
> According to my calculations a chunk should be 12KB + a little bit (Let's just say 16KB). 16*16*16*3. 3 is for a byte and a short(3 bytes).

That's bad. Though you're keeping the size of the `HashMap` secret, I can see you're too optimistic.

A `Map.Entry` is an object. Add 4 or 8 bytes for its header.

Its key is an object, never a primitive. Count 8 bytes.

The same for the value.

A `HashMap.Entry` stores the hash (`int`, 4 bytes) and a reference to `Entry next` (4 or 8 bytes). The `HashMap` maintains an array of references to its entries (4 or 8 bytes per element), which by default kept at most 75% full.

So we have much more that what you expected. The exact values depends on your JVM and some of my above figures may be wrong. Anyway, you're off by a factor of at maybe 10 or more.

I'd suggest you to post you code to [CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java) with all the details needed for the size estimation. Consider using some [primitive map](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=java+primitive+map) or maybe just an array...

Comment: I'd recommend re-thinking your system completely. The `HashMap` solution pretty much explodes with a reasonably amount of tiles.

Comment: Unless it is very sparse, an array is almost certainly more efficient than a map with byte keys.